# The similarities and differences between electron transfer and charge transfer

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry

Please explain the similarities and differences among electron transfer,electron transport, charge transfer, and charge transport from the molecular, atomic and electronic levels.

Is *electron transfer* different from *electron transport*?

Is *charge transfer* different from *charge transport*?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking but electron 'transfer' is different to 'transport' in the sense that transport ultimately involves many electron transfers events one after the other. Charge transport is the same as electron transport.

There is is difference between electron transfer and charge transfer. Charge transfer is usually associated with charge transfer complexes, such as TTF-TCNQ (tetrathiofulvalene-tetracyanoquinodimethane) but there are very many others. In these complexes the charge transfer from one species to the other occurs as the photon is absorbed so that the lowest excited state is $\ce{D + A + photon -> D+A-}$. This often means that these complexes are highly coloured.

In electron transfer no photon is needed and the process follows Marcus theory whereby a barrier is crossed between $\ce{D + A}$ and $\ce{D+ + A-}$, i.e. this is a thermal process with an activation barrier. The unusual feature of Marcus transfer is the that activation energy has a parabolic dependence on energy thus the rate constant can be slow in both endothermic and very exothermic conditions.